# Rotate/Spin object in Unity using touch (example video)

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, vector, rotation, quaternions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQINoSwvmto

My goal is to rotate the object just like how it's done in Photoshop (video above)
I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've tried several solutions i saw here  but none worked. they either used the objects up vector to "look at" or just used one axis instead of calculating the angle between the first touch and the latest touch. There lies my second problem, when I tried that solution sometimes the angles would come out janky and the object would spin weirdly

Comment: Just found this guy's example. This is what I'm trying to get https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkxmheqhd-s

Comment: Got closer to a solution by using previous and current mouseclick and treating it on a per quadrant/axis basis to simulate rotation

Comment: If you're still having issues, please be sure to include a [mcve] for others to see, and describe in detail how your current code fails to meet your objectives. Otherwise you won't be able to get any helpful answers.